# Mongodb do a find and filter by difference of days

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to get some documents that have a difference of days greater than 4

I want compare the currect day with 'fechaActualizacion'

example (using js and Moment):

```
moment().diff(fechaActualizada, 'days') > 4
```

This is my schema:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  fechaActualizacion: { $lte: new Date(Date.now() - 4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString() }
});
```